# Pick 4 elements of a list and make a number that is a square of other

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of some numbers, and I need to pick 4 of them that can make a number which will be like `sqrt(sum_of_nums) % 1 = 0`, problem is I don't know how to pick them

Comment: your question is not clear. Also, show us what you tried?

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to pick 4 numbers from a list can be:

```
from itertools import combinations
nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list(combinations(nums,4))
```

Now you can find the sum of these numbers by:

```
[sum(x) for x in list(combinations(nums,4))]

#output

[10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 16, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Now you can filter the perfect squares by:

```
[sum(x) for x in list(combinations(nums,4))if sum(x)**0.5 % 1 ==0]

#output

[16, 16]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I have never had idea how to do that!